# Special characters not registered properly in db jQuery Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile, special-characters

I'm making a phonegap (1.4.1) Jquery Mobile (JQM 1.1 Jq 1.7.1) app the main function of which is submitting a form through Ajax but special characters (here å ä ö) sent through the app won't register in the database correctly.

Note: I have no control of the server / script on the receiving end so solutions can't be based on making changes to the server.
There is a web based non-ajax form which registers special characters correctly.

```
var dataString = $("#klinikkurt").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://doit.medfarm.uu.se/script/kurt2/receive.php",
    data: dataString,
    timeout: 20000,
    datatype: "html",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
    success: ...
 });
```

I've tried both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8
and I've also tried adding

```
dataString = encodeURIComponent(dataString)
```

and

```
dataString = escape(dataString)
```

I have tried all solutions I've yet to come across. But alas no cigar.

Update: ÅÄÖåäö registers as Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶

Comment: what kind of special characters are you trying to push in ? what kind of problems do you come across ?

Comment: If you have formatted your data as UTF-8 and saved all your files as UTF-8, there's not much more you can do, and often times this problem is serverside, requiring things like setting UTF-8 specifically in MySQL or other DB's, and without access to the server or DB your pretty much screwed.

Comment: The characters are mainly the Swedish ÅÄÖ / åäö and they register as Ã_Ã_Ã_Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶. Note that ÅÄÖ / åäö sent through the web based form are registered correctly so the server is able to register them correctly. It just doesn't when sent through the app.